# git ignore file completely

Tags: git, gitignore

I am using `git` to organise my code in better way.

I have setup `git` on `localhost` and `production server`

There is a median `GitLab` to store all commits and branches.

On the `server`, I have setup two subdomains, one to host `master` branch on `app.example.com` and another one for `dev` branch on `dev.example.com`

I have initialized and set up the same remote on both subdomains to pull master branch to `app` and dev branch to `dev`.

**I want some files to be separate in all three places.**

Like I have two files in my application `database_config.php` and `app.php`

`database_config.php` file contains the database credentials and since database credentials for `localhost`, `app` and `dev` are different. I need it to be different and not be affected by merge, push and pull.

Similarly, I have `app.php` through which `debug` is enabled on `localhost` and `dev` but it will always be disabled on `app`.

although I have included these files in `.gitignore` file on localhost, it is not pushed to `GitLab`. When in case of conflict I need to `reset` HEAD on production which also deletes the both files on production because they does not exists on `GitLab` repository.

**How can I prevent these files from any action of the git and it will always be intact of any event?**

Comment: First of all it is a bad practice to checkin credentials in a source repository. Secondly you are eseentially using git for configuration management/deployment. You should consider tools that are more suitable for the job e.g. chef or ansible

Comment: I'm not pushing credentials to repository. That's why it is in `gitignore` file. I mean to say that on hard reset, local files are deleted because they are not in git. How to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a file to .gitignore, it must be untracked. Remove it using `git rm --cached database_config.php`.